# How do I translate "willpower"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do I translate *willpower*, for example in the following sentence?

> Willpower alone is often not enough to overcome addiction.

Comment: Volpovo?   Short and consists of other roots, right?

Comment: @CharlotteSL It is not clear. Volpovo can mean the ability to have a will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[John Wells' dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) doesn't have an entry for “willpower”, but it does have one for “determination” which is probably a synonym:

> **determination** obstino, firmeco, neŝanceleblo, rezoluteco

Out of these I think *rezoluteco* is probably the most appropriate. PIV gives the following definition:

> **rezolut/a.** Firma en siaj projektoj; senhezita en la plenumado de siaj decidoj: *rezoluta karaktero; rezolute apliki agitplanon.*

I think this definition is suitable for the example phrase you have given.

Comment: Yes, _resoluteko_ is the word  I would use, probably because it's close to Italian.

Answer (score 4):

Neil's answer is good but don't overlook ***volforto***.

To have a strong will is *ĉiam havi firman/fortan volon*.